# Why does microsoft not recommend seeding roles using EF Core model seed data

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

According to MSDN: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding

> If your scenario includes any of the following it is recommended to
> use custom initialization logic described in the last section:
>
> Data that requires calls to external API,
> such as ASP.NET Core Identity roles and users creation

However when I use

```
        var roleBuilder = modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>();
            .HasData(
                new IdentityRole
                {
                    Id = "2c5e174e-3b0e-446f-86af-483d56fd7210", // Hardcoded to prevent creating a new one.
                    Name = "Administrator", 
                    NormalizedName = "Administrator".ToUpper()
                });
```

It works, so what is the reason I shouldn't do this?

Answer (score 0):

Because seeding data can be "captured" in migration snapshots so it is better to seed only static data. Data that depends an external API are obviously not static and can be changed outside of migrations.

Comment: So the recommended way is to manually run a script to seed I guess

Comment: Yes, something that is friendly with the initialization logic of that kind of data.